# How to match against multiple value possiblities in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have list of person names in column A.

I want to display "1" in column B for names which end with either "e" or "i" or "n".

If there would be only one match to test against, I would write something like:

`=IF( MID(A1,FIND(" ",B1)-1,1) = "e", "1", "0")`

In PHP I would solve that like this:

`echo in_array( $names[$row_number], array('e', 'i', 'n') ) ? '1' : '0';`

What formula should I use in column B in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR like this to search for multiple letters

`=IF(OR(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1,1)={"e","i","n"}),1,0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:-

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1,1)={"e","i","n"}),1,0)
```

Comment: This is so far the shortest solution. I tested it and it works. However, I don't understand how OR() works here. Looks as if there is only one expression in it's argument list...

Comment: @Henno: Here `OR` works as like this `=OR(A1="e", A1="i", A1="n")` which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: @Henno, your existing formula with MID implies that you are looking for "e" as the last letter of the first name (the letter before the space) rather than the last letter in the cell, hence my answer using MID too but utilising OR....

Comment: @barry You are right! I missed that until now. The reason it worked for me was that by chance I actually had only the first name in the A column when I tested this. Silly me. :-)